# How to find the overlapping of an image on TkInter Canvas (Python)?

Tags: python

In Tkinter, when I create an image on a canvas and find the coordinates of it, it only returns two coordinates, so the find_overlapping method doesn't work with it (naturally). Is there an alternative?

Comment: How did you "find the coordinates" of the image?  What do the coordinates you have represent?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the image's bounding box (bbox) by calling `bbox = canvas.bbox(imageID)`.  Then you can use `canvas.find_overlapping(*bbox)`.

Answer (score -1):

The coordinates it returns should be the coordinates of the top left corner of the image. So if the coordinates you got were `(x, y)`, and your image object (assuming it's a PhotoImage) is `img`, then you can do:

```
w, h = img.width(), img.height()
find_overlapping(x, y, x + w, y + h)
```